# Need to update GIT 'master' before I am able to push to GIT 'branch'

Tags: git

I have a simple GIT environment setup for my development. One is the master that is cloned off the remote master and another is a branch (exists on remote as well). I typically work on the branch and then when I want to push my changes, I do the usual Git command sequence like:

1. git pull (to make sure everything is up to date)
2. git add
3. git commit -m "message"
4. git push

When I do '**git push**', I get a message stating :

```
d96001d..d1cf61c  branch_release -> branch_release
[rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '____________'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration variable
hint: to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

To resolve this, i switch branches like this

```
git checkout master.
```

This brings in a horde of files into my Master that prelude with the prefix 'M' meaning they were modified. Then I do

```
git checkout branch_release
```

and it seems to bring in the same set of files into my master as well, which I am thinking should not happen since I did a GIT pull on this branch before.

My question is, is this by design that I also need to update the master before I do a push on one of it's branches? If not, how have I set this incorrectly and what should I do to ensure that i only need to update the GIT Branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resolve the *non-fast-forword* error you have to **pull before you push**. The error says that the **remote master** has commits that **your master** doesnt have.

If you just do a push, without specifiying the branch, it pushes all branches. You can either specify a **default push branch[2]** or **specify it by command[1]**.

**[1] specify it by push command parameter**

So you probably want to do a (push with speficied branch)

```
git push origin branch_release
```

**[2] define default push branch**

I think this might be helpful:

- http://jimkubicek.com/blog/2012/08/16/git-push-current-branch/

According to this site you can specify a *default push branch* like this:

> git config --global push.default current

**[edit]**

As **torek** pointed out *simple* will be the new git default value by git version 2.0. So updating will (in the future) solve this problem/question .

> git config --global push.default simple

You can read more about this here:

- https://coderwall.com/p/dnofpw

Comment: If you have a new enough git, `git config --global push.default simple` is what will be the new "default default" in git 2.0, and may be a better recommendation for those who are new to git, or even sort of "intermediate level" users.  (But, like flavors of ice cream or how much garlic to put in food, the "best answer" is a matter of taste.)

Comment: Well, it was OK before, too, I just figured I'd add the note about `simple`.  Now it has one technical error as git 2.0 is not yet out, but whenever git 2.0 does come out, updating will indeed solve it! :-)